# Limit Array Length - Failure?

Tags: php, arrays

A visitor log on one of my sites just lost all visitors.  It's been working for a year and a half but all entries were lost overnight.  The log page is here (if you visit one of the site pages, your information will be added to the log):
http://mykindred.com/dalton/hoax/viewlog.php

The log is kept in a text file ($filename) which should limit to $maxloglines = 300. $logline contains the new visitor to be added to the log.  The code that generates the log:

```
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$logline .= implode("\n", array_slice($lines, 0, $maxloglines));
file_put_contents($filename, $logline);
```

Any suggestions as to why my log would lose its entries? Do I have a coding error?

Comment: Is it possible that what you're logging may have had additional line breaks in it? Was the file emptied entirely or were there 300 empty lines?

Comment: It's possible you tried to read while writing maybe? You should probably lock the file to prevent this. See the notes about the 'c' mode:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: @davids3 The code shown removes empty lines, and the log was full yesterday (i.e. had 300 entries).

Comment: @Paul Bain Not locking the file may be what happened? Perhaps someone viewed the log while it was being accessed by the logging code. I will add locking to the function. thanks.

Comment: I'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

When writing files using `file_put_contents`, you are essentially using a series of  `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` where the file is opened with file mode `w`:

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the
>   file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist,
>   attempt to create it.

As you do not have an exclusive lock on the file, it is possible to read the file at the point at which the file has been truncated and the file pointer placed at the start. In this case, the contents of your `file()` command would be empty.

Instead, you should use the option `LOCK_EX` to secure an exclusive lock of the file while writing:

```
file_put_contents($filename, $logline, LOCK_EX);
```

You can read more about that at in the [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) documentation.